# Pipenv not setting PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pipenv

I have the following structure

```
.
├── module1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── start.py
├── module2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── settings.py
└── Pipfile
```

cat module1/start.py

```
from module2.settings import VAR

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(VAR)
```

cat module2/settings.py

```
VAR = 'foo'
```

If I try to run my program I get

```
pipenv shell
python module1/start.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module1/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module2.settings import VAR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

or

```
pipenv run python module1/start.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module1/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module2.settings import VAR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

Why doesn't pipenv set PYTHONPATH correctly ?

Answer (score 6):

I realized I can use *.env* files to setup PYTHONPATH and make pipenv use it.

```
echo "PYTHONPATH=${PWD}" >> .env
```

Comment: It's safer to use `>>`:

`echo "PYTHONPATH=${PWD}" >> .env`